# Git difftool shows equal files

Tags: git, kdiff3

I'm using kdiff3 as a difftool. When I use git difftool command it also shows me the files that are exactly the same. Even kdiff3 pops up a message that the files are "binary equal" (they are text files though). Is there a way to avoid displaying unchanged files?

Comment: At what stage in the git workflow are you at? What goes `git status` say?

Comment: @DuncanLock everything is added and commited

Comment: Do you mean that git difftool is just showing you every file in your tree, most of which are unchanged, some of which are? Does `git status` list all the files too, or only the changed ones? i.i do `git status` and `git difftool` agree about which files have changed?

Comment: @DuncanLock It doesn's show all files. Just some (hard to guess the pattern). Git status shows nothing.

Comment: If you've changed permissions on some of the files, or line endings, or only made whitespace changes, you can get confusing stuff showing up in diffs - but I have no idea why `git difftool` would indicate that files have outstanding changes when `git status` doesn't?

Comment: @DuncanLock I have no idea too. :)

Comment: What happens if you use `git diff` instead of `difftool` - i.e. use the command line diff instead of kdiff3?

Comment: @DuncanLock It shows the "changes" in red text, though the both versions are the same. (just like difftool).

Comment: I have this same issue.  I used `git-svn` to clone a Subversion branch. When a couple dozen files appeared as "modified" after the clone, and issuing a `git checkout` on one of those files did not remove it from the modified list, I thought it was a line ending/`core.autocrlf` issue. But it doesn't appear to be the whole story, since `git difftool` with KDiff3 says the files are "binary equal".

Comment: I solved my issue mentioned in the previous comment by creating a `.git/info/attributes` file which contains `* -text` to prevent any EOL conversions in addition to setting `core.autocrlf` to `false`. After doing another `git svn clone`, I no longer had "phantom modified" files.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Beyond Compare as my difftool. For me, this was a line endings issue.

I noticed that the when I ran git diff (instead of git difftool) the same files that I saw showing up with no changes in Beyond Compare were showing up with the messages

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in <path to file>
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

You might say "But wait, I know it isn't a line endings issue because when I open it up in Kdiff3, it doesn't show any line ending changes." That has to do with the "The file will have its original line endings in your working directory" part of that warning message.

I consider myself a pretty competent git user, but I'll admit that I've never had the courage to really dig into how it handles line ending changes. So I don't know all the details but I know that git can do some behind the scenes magic to show you the line endings that your OS likes even if that's not exactly what is stored in the repository.

I was able to get around the weird files by following [these](https://www.rtuin.nl/2013/02/how-to-make-git-ignore-different-line-endings/) instructions and making my .git/info/attribute file look like this:

```
* -crlf
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have enabled some Preprocessor command in Diff(under Config), that's why the binary maybe same.

If you want to hide them then you need to do **Full analysis** under Directory -> File Comparison Mode (Full analysis). It would hide the processed files.

But first step is to check it in another diff application (as usual make sure the file endings are matched or ignored).